# How to add UITabbarController to UIViewController in iOs

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How to push Viewcontroller with TabbarController? In Viewcontroller'XIB, i created UITabbarController. Then i push this ViewController, but it not appear UITabbarController.
This is my code:
*Viewcontroller.h:

```
 @interface StatusViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

    IBOutlet UIButton *UploadButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *ConvertorButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *CompletedButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@end
```

*Viewcontroller.m:

```
@implementation StatusViewController
@synthesize tabBarController ;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self createTabView];
}
-(void)createTabView
{
    ....

    ....
    [ConvertorButton addSubview:Label3];

    [CompletedButton setTag:3];


    [CompletedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay-2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [CompletedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [CompletedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    //[[CompletedButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    // [[CompletedButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];

    UILabel *Label4=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 8, 70, 30)];
    [Label4 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [Label4 setText:@"Completed"];


    Label4.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [Label4 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
    Label4.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [CompletedButton addSubview:Label4];

    // [self selectTab:1];

    [self.view addSubview:UploadButton];

    [self.view addSubview:ConvertorButton];

    [self.view addSubview:CompletedButton];


}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The question Which You have presented here is not understandable ..Plz Make it proper ?

Comment: you change your rootview dynamically , You can do that . What is need of pushing UITabbarcontoller

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If You want to use UITabBarController in your UIViewController class then use this below code...

UIViewController .h Class -

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *tab;
```

UIViewController .m Class -

Add this in ViewDidLoad method...

```
    self.tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    // FirstViewController
    First *fvc=[[First alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    fvc.title=@"First";
    fvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"i.png"];

    //SecondViewController
    Second *svc=[[Second alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    svc.title=@"Second";
    svc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"im.png"];

    //ThirdViewController
    Third *tvc=[[Third alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    tvc.title=@"Third";
    tvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];

    self.tab.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fvc, svc, tvc, nil];

    [self.view addSubview:self.tab.view];
```

here First, Second and Third are three different UIViewControllers. And you don't need to give the action on Tabs.

It will work...

Comment: Thanks, i tried your code, it works but tabbaritem is not at botton position. I don't know why?

Comment: ok..are you creating the project for normal screen 320 * 480....It wont show you for 320 * 568 screen. You should set the frame coordinates according to you screen size..

Comment: I hv seen you sceenshot, Definitely u are using iphone (Retina 4.0 inch) simulator..

Comment: self.tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        // code for 4-inch screen
        //  LoginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 518, 80, 49);
        self.tab.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,568);
    }
    else if (screenBounds.size.height == 1024)
    {
        //code for ipad
        
    }
    else
    {
        // code for 3.5-inch screen
        //  LoginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 80, 49);
       self.tab.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
    }
but it not correct

Comment: yes, it is totally wrong dude.. where you want tab bar in your screen bottom or top..????

Comment: I want tabbar at bottom

Comment: I have a problem: When push viewcontroller, it show tabbar controller correct but i want to click on tabbar item, it show navigation bar at top of of viewcontroller that clicked on tabbaritem  instead navigation bar of root viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

If you're are starter,best practice is to search in google for the latest api samples,then understand the code and make your own world.

1) You can find the related sample codes from apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

2) [TweetieBar](https://github.com/jparishy/Tweetie-Style-UITabBarController) --Here is the sample code with custom TabBarController(TweetieTabBar)