# Custom Tabbar in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have **Six Tabbar controller** in my iPhone Application. so  i want see all Tab in single view (No more Tab want to need). so I Want to make Tabbar using **Custom button**. My problem is that when I click on first tab then it display first view controller then I click on Firstviewcontroller then it display the Child view controller of FirstView controller. then after I click on second tab  then open second view controller and click on second view controller display the child of subviewcontroller . then after I click on first tab how to I know that use last navigate particular that view .

**Note** :- I am using UINavigationController.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: I guess nobody can help you just reading and imagining how you explain your app navigation flow. Try to sketch your storyboard or take a screenshot of your actual storyboard if you're using one!

Comment: @NapsterSee my answer, It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142952/how-to-add-uitabbarcontroller-to-uiviewcontroller-in-ios

Comment: Do you have 6 tabs or 6 tabView controller ?

Comment: @AshutoshMishra : I want 6 tab in one tabbarview controller.

Comment: How may TabBarView Controller you have as you have 6 tabs in one tabBarViewController?

Comment: he want to get last opened uiviewcontroller click on differnet custom tab he want to do same functionality like uitabbar based application in custom tabbar .

Answer (score 0):

Use This code....

```
self.tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

// FirstViewController
First *fvc=[[First alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
fvc.title=@"First";
fvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"i.png"];

//SecondViewController
Second *svc=[[Second alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
svc.title=@"Second";
svc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"im.png"];

//ThirdViewController
Third *tvc=[[Third alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
tvc.title=@"Third";
tvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
.
.
.
.//Like this Create Six tabBar item.
.
.
.

// Add All six Tab bars in your UITabViewController
self.tab.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fvc, svc, tvc,........, nil];

[self.view addSubview:self.tab.view];
```

It will work, Happy Coding..

Comment: Your answer is working fine when we have to show five tab in tabbar. If we have to more then five then it will automatically show "More" button and display other tab. I want to all six tab in single tab controller. I do not need More button.

Comment: yeah..it will show one more tab button, after click on this tab shows rest tab bar items...Better you will place six UIButtons in one UIView and give the action, it seems like UITabBarController..

Comment: Hey if you add with above code then it will display more if we add more than five tabbar. And as i said I have to display six tabbar in screen not more button. You answer is fine but it will show more button if we add navigation controller in it.