# iOS 7: different navigation items for tab bar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am relative new with the iOS app development. Currently I am developing a small app with a tab bar. The problem I am facing is that I would like to have different navigation items foreach tab. I tried a lot of things, but things aren't working. I am programming in the native iOS language.

In my app I've got a AppDelegate. In my AppDelegate there is a little piece of code for setting up my mainViewController:

```
- (void)setupOverlordViewController
{
    MainViewController *rootVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = navVC;
}
```

I am setting up my tabs in my MainViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIViewController *tabView1 = [[Tab1ViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *tabView2 = [[Tab2ViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *tabView3 = [[Tab3ViewController alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:tabView1];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:tabView2];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:tabView3];

    [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];

    tabView1.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TabView1", nil)
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabView1.png"]
                                    tag:1];

    tabView2.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TabView2", nil)
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabView2.png"]
                                    tag:2];
    tabView3.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"TabView3", nil)
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabView3.png"]
                                    tag:3];
}
```

Each View (tabView1, tabView2, tabView3) has there own layout, which is set in the ViewDidLoad method of the View. When I would like to add navigation buttons in the navigation bar by adding them in the ViewDidLoad method, but it seems impossible to add  the buttons. The only way to add them is directly in my MainViewController, but then I can't set the navigation bar buttons different foreach tab.

The code for adding the buttons to my navigation bar is as follows:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnNewRecord = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self      action:@selector(btnNewRecord)];


NSArray *rightItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnNewRecord, nil];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:rightItems];
```

Could somebody explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @P Griep here is my answer.. pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142952/how-to-add-uitabbarcontroller-to-uiviewcontroller-in-ios/18143514#18143514

Comment: @P Griep, are you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a example for you by using xib files. I have created three View Controllers and added them to navigation controllers. Following the `appdelegate` code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *firstNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: firstVC];

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *secondNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: secondVC];

    ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *thirdNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: thirdVC];

    NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:firstNavVC];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:secondNavVC];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:thirdNavVC];

    firstNavVC.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"First", nil)
                                  image:nil
                                    tag:1];

    secondNavVC.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Second", nil)
                                  image:nil
                                    tag:2];
    thirdNavVC.tabBarItem =
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Third", nil)
                                  image:nil
                                    tag:3];

    UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabbarController.viewControllers = tabViewControllers;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Following is the output :

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can download code example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3hob1jqf0riwsu/TabBarController.zip)

Comment: This isn't working for me. My tab bar at the bottom of the screen shows now only the background color, but the tabs are somehow responding when I press the background color. The navigation items are still not visible.

Comment: @PGriep, are you using storyboards or xibs?

Comment: There is no need to create a MainViewController. You can directly set your UITabbarController instance as root View controller of UIWindow.

Comment: How do I assign the array tabViewControllers to the self.window.rootViewController? Xcode gives me errors.

Comment: Thx for your help. Your code runs perfectly. With some minor adjustments it works fine for my application!

Answer (score 0):

you need separate navigation controller for each tab bar view controller & then you can add UIBarButtonItem on each navigation controller.

Comment: I did that as the answer of Naga Mallesh Maddali, but it is still not working.

Comment: did you set your UITabbarController instance as root View controller of UIWindow?