# What's the way to assign an item in a Tab Bar to a View Controller using Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, tabs

I set up a view with a tab bar by dragging it out of the object library in Xcode 6, along with tab items. Now how do I assign each of those tab items to a new view controller?

I attempted ctrl + mousepad drag to from the tab item to a view controller but did not work. Is there a different approach to connecting a tab bar item to a view with the method of creating the tab bar by dragging out of the object library?

I am trying to do it using Storyboard and manually rather than coding. Would there be a way to achieve that with what I described?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7: different navigation items for tab bar controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200014/ios-7-different-navigation-items-for-tab-bar-controller)

Comment: @Jaideep I am trying to just use Storyboard and the Object Library. Is there a method to do so by just using them?

Comment: Try putting navigation controller on storyboard dropping a segue on it from tab item.